# Setting a variable to a Matrix field with additional parameters

Tags: craft3, matrix, elementcriteriamodel

I'm trying to set a variable to a Matrix field and apply additional query parameters like so:

```
{% set monthDates = entry.scanDates.type('dates').date('and', '>= ' ~ currMonthFirst|date('Y-m-d'), '< ' ~ nextMonthFirst|date('Y-m-d')) %}
```

I want to have a set of dates based on a date range, but I'm getting a "Calling unknown method: craft\behaviors\ElementQueryBehavior::date()"

The name of the Matrix field is `scanDates` with block type `dates` and field name `date`.

The following code with just one parameter works just fine, so it must be the syntax that is wrong in the first example.

```
{% set monthDates = entry.scanDates.type('dates').date('>= ' ~ nextMonthFirst|date('Y-m-d')) %}
```

What is the correct syntax to narrow down the results based on multiple conditions?  `

Comment: I am having the same issue—did you ever find a solution? Thanks.

Comment: @univers_ I wasn't able to figure out why it wasn't working so I found a different way to do what I need.